# Secure documents on website using php, pdf, doc, docx

Tags: php, document

Doing some research on trying to secure documents on a server so that visitors cannot copy paste the content.

Users can upload documents as pdf, doc, docx, and currently they can download these files in staging enviroment. Anyone know of a way I could either upload these as read only so once they are downloaded they cannot be edited or copy pasted etc?

Or is there a way I could get the contents of these files and display the content on a webpage while disabling copy paste etc?

Just looking for some ideas on a solution for this.

Comment: In short, no, you cannot - you can never trust the client to enforce arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: By displaying their contents as images.

Comment: In short, you need a perfect DRM system. Call up RIAA and the MPAA and see how that's working out for them...

Comment: I want visitors to be able to download the files, I'm not trying to prevent them from downloading, only prevent them from copy pasting the data... As sємsєм said displaying them as images could work, but then I need to figure out a way to get the doc contents and convert to images etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control web browser behavior.

The only way to do that is to use a script to render a part of a document.
For example, rendering page by page in a web view. But user could copy/past content even if you deploy some Javascript.

Perhaps, you should take a look to Flash, Silverlight or Java applet.
I think there are few solutions that can limit access to read only.
But il will mainly limited to computers.

You can protect a file with a password too.
Files could be downloaded but only users owning the password could edit them.
This is the case for PDF files, Excel files, etc.
It's a way but I don't think it's the best way.

I think the easiest way is to convert your documents as PDF files and to limit actions to read only by adding a password. You ll be able to disable write permission, print permission, etc. And rendering a PDF on a web page is very simple.